# Best way to pass same data to two React components?

Tags: reactjs

I currently have two React components one that maintains a user inputted list of objects ex: `[{"good1":"$10"},{"good2":"$15"}]` and another component that lets the user create a list and use the goods as tags. However I am having trouble on how to pass data that is in the state of GoodManage to ListManager, I also have a wrapper for the layout. I tried passing the state from the LayoutManager into the GoodManager and having it update the goods list, and send that same list to ListManager, but it only seems to work once.

```
class LayoutManager extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {"goods":[{"good1":"$1"}]};
    }
    updateGoods(goods){
        this.setState({"goods":goods});
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div className="layout-manager">
                <div className="good-manager container">
                    <GoodManager update={this.updateGoods.bind(this)} goods={this.state.goods}/>
                </div>
                <div className="list-mananger container">
                    <ListManager goods={this.state.goods}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you described its working only first time, it means you are storing the goods value in the `state` variable of `ListManager` component in `constructor`, it will save only the initial list since `constructor` only get called on first `rendering` not on `re-endering`, so you need to use `lifecycle` method `componentWillReceiveProps`, it will get called when any change happen to `props` values, at that time you need to update the `state` values, use this method in `ListManager` component:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProp){
    this.setState({goods: nextProps.goods});
}
```

Reference: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops